# Stop Loading Screen in android as soon as data loaded from mysql

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse, splash-screen

I am working on android project in which I have to apply loading screen until the data loads from database. I know that how to start proegressBar but I need to know how can I stop the loading screen as data loaded from database.If u can please give me one simple example from which I can understand that how can I do this because I am new to android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are getting data from a database you should do it asynchronously.
The best way to do it would be using an AsyncTask.

```
class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //get data from DB here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }       
}
```

And to make it execute: `new GetDataTask().execute();`